# Python SQLITE3 update column value based on where condition applied to a table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite table that I wanted to update. This table ('abc') already has a row inserted through some other process for id and useremail. Now, I want my query to lookup this record based on where condition (on useremail) and update the value of column logintime. I am pretty new to Sqlite so need some help in figuring it out. Code below -

creating a new table (works OK)

```
conn = sql.connect('/content/sample_data/userlogs.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc (
         id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
         useremail TEXT,
         logintime TEXT,
         logouttime TEXT
);
""")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

code for inserting a record (works OK)

```
email = ['jojo@jojo.com']
conn = sql.connect('/content/sample_data/userlogs.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('insert into abc (useremail) values(?)', email)
```

code for updating column logintime where value in column useremail = email:

```
conn = sql.connect('/content/sample_data/userlogs.db')
c = conn.cursor()
now = datetime.now()
c.execute('UPDATE abc SET logintime = ? WHERE useremail = ?', (now, email))
```

I am having trouble with this c.execute statement.

Comment: What error does it print?

Comment: I think it MIGHT be something with the strings. Try using """ instead of ' when creating a query string. Eg: """UPDATE abc SET logintime = ? WHERE useremail = ?"""

Comment: Luckily.. I found the solution. The column was defined as type TEXT, but I was trying to update it with date (datetime.now()). I had to convert "now" to string, with no change to the update statement, I am able to update my table.